# Смена профиля деятельности

Tags: работа

Несколько лет я занимаюсь бизнес-приложениями. Последнее время я подумываю о том, что программирование микроконтроллеров как-то престижнее что ли. По крайней мере, я вполне понимаю аргументы критиков дотнета, они явно небезосновательны. Но писать программы, аналогичные тем, что я пишу, на неуправляемых языках не сильно тянет, потому что я не готов обходиться, как минимум, без рефлексии, интерпретируемых лямбда-выражений и атрибутов.

По моим текущим компетенциям предложения работы есть. Но я бы хотел завязать с бизнес-приложениями и переключиться на микроконтроллеры. Есть ли возможность сделать это без больших потерь в зарплате?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разработка ПО под контроллеры - это в 95% случаев чистый С, хотя на каких-нибудь "толстых" чипах это могут быть и C++. О managed-языках на контроллерах придётся забыть, это пока ещё очень большая редкость, так как обычно от контроллеров требуется максимальное быстродействие (об использовании Real-Time Java в мелких железках слышал всего один раз, потому считаю это экзотикой), и минимум кода (кроме случаев "толстых" контроллеров, типа ATMega).

По зарплате - в среднем в России разработчик по железкам получать будет в любом случае меньше, чем энтерпрайз-девелопер. Не уважают у нас "железячников", да и спрос на них невысок ("оборонка" либо мелкие конторки, ведь своё производство у нас полностью убили ещё в 90-х). Потому "железячники" сваливают в дальнее зарубежье (у меня пара сокурсников уехали в Ю.Корею, трудятся на очень приличной зарплате в Samsung'е, где набор разработчиков close-to-hardware никогда не прекращается).

Порог вхождения в отрасль разработки под микроконтроллеры достаточно высок, так как кроме знания языка будет нужно освоить не одну аппаратную платформу, и хорошо бы ещё иметь представление о принципах работы цифровой электроники.

Я сам по специальности являюсь разработчиком промышленной электроники ("программирование контроллеров" это только малая часть того, чем я мог бы продолжать заниматься профессионально), однако я предпочёл уйти из этой отрасли почти сразу, ибо перспектив там нет, особенно зарплатных. Сейчас пишу на "плюсах" разного рода приложения под разные платформы, но параллельно изучаю J2EE-разработку, поскольку a) спрос на Java только растёт, b) зарплата джаверов уже сейчас выше, чем у плюсовиков, и тенденция сохраняется.

Так что я бы на вашем месте из сферы бизнес-приложений не уходил. В нашей стране, перейдя в стан "железячников", в деньгах потеряете точно. А чтобы попасть в тот же Samsung, скиллы по разработке под "железо" надо иметь очень и очень существенные, чему нужно обучаться довольно приличное время.

Comment: Совершенно верно. Хотя кроме толстых ATMega сейчас всё больше контроллеров с ARM'ами разных типов (стартом были, если не ошибаюсь atmel'овские SAM'ы)

Answer (score 3):

Всё зависит от того, какая у вас зарплата. Но вообще, я полагаю, что это маловероятно, чтобы у вас получилось заработать на микроконтроллерах столько же. Надо быть очень скиловым человеком с опытом.

> программирование микроконтроллеров как-то престижнее что ли

Гнаться надо не за престижем, а за той работой, которой вам интереснее заниматься и где вам конфортнее. Как говорится, работа ради жизни, а не жизнь ради работы. Если не хотите писать на неуправляемых языках.. так не пишите и не тратьте нервы. Престиж тут совершенно ни при чём. А те кто "вякает" про дотнет в 99% понятия не имеют, о чём говорят. Кроме того, какое вам дело, кто и что там говорит? Важно, что вы достигли некоторого успеха с дотнетом (и не только вы), а остальные холивары не имеют никакого значения, и пусть остальные дальше завидуют ;)

Comment: Судя по докладу известного рекрутёра на конференции по программированию - где-то вдвое меньше, чем должна быть исходя из моих скиллов. Кстати, Вы пропустили в моём тезисе словосочетание "аналогичные тем, что я пишу". Именно те задачи, которые я решаю, тяжело решать без рефлексии, атрибутов и лямбд. Насколько я понимаю, в микроконтроллерах другие задачи.

Comment: Ну ради интереса посмотрите на FRP-Yampa, язык Hume (хотя основной язык - C). А так, при программировании микроконтроллеров часто не в языках дело - затрагивается много смежных дисциплин - электроника, теория управления (в т.ч. с нечёткой логикой), цифровая обработка сигналов. Ну и предметная область, но это как везде.

Answer (score 0):

> программирование микроконтроллеров как-то престижнее что ли

Это достаточно спорное утверждение. На престижность работы влияют востребованность, оплачиваемость, новизна, перспективы профессии, а также значимость компании-работодателя на рынке. Причем эти характеристики могут противоречить друг другу.

Например, разработка обозревателя Хром для Google или разработка драйверов для процессоров Intel (и то, и то возможно, например, в Санкт-Петербурге). Что престижней сказать затруднительно. А оплата и там, и там будет примерно одинакова (по разрядам).

Возможность найти оплачиваемую работу по низкоуровневому программированию безусловно есть. Например, это Siemens, NS Networks, Motorola и подобные компании, которые производят не только программное обеспечение, а какое-то "железо".

Comment: То, что я понимал под "как-то престижнее что ли" подразумевает, скорее, некую элитарность, связанную с высоким порогом вхождения. То есть, тема микроконтроллеров привлекает меня именно с этой стороны. Вопрос, скорее, в том, насколько реально быстро перескочить в эту область с минимальными потерями.